# AVFoundation scan QRCode isn't working

Tags: ios

Use system native SDK AVFoundation scan qr code, when the qr code contrast is not high, scanning not to come out
[QRCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6opmP.png)
[my demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAeIm.png)

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: I have just uploaded a picture of my code